# iOS app crashes when device is tilted to landscape orientation

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios8

Working on an app for iOS 8 using Swift. It is only supposed to be supported in portrait orientation mode.

The app runs without issue if it starts in portrait mode and does not get tilted such that the device is in landscape mode. It also runs without issue if the device STARTS in landscape mode and either stays in this mode or is tilted to portrait mode.

When the phone moves from portrait to landscape mode the app crashes every time. The error is of type EXC_BAD_ACCESS and gives an address. The UI highlights the first line of the `AppDelegate` class.

info.plist has been changed to express the fact that only portrait mode is supported. In addition, I tried overriding the method `shouldAutorotate()` in the root view controller. However, I think this is a memory issue.

What information do I need to find a solution for this issue? Can anyone point me towards resources for dealing with memory issues in iOS 8?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about memory in iOS 8 over any other OS.  Xcode also comes with a ton of useful tools to help you out.  I suggest you use the allocations instrument in Instruments, use zombies, use guardmalloc, attach to the process with lldb, trigger the crash.

Look through the allocations to see where it was allocated and track its lifecycle.

Use lldb to figure out values and inspect the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

This happens for us, Apple's spinning animation starts to occur, then lags, then the whole phone restarts. Seems Apple has memory management issues with their built in spinning animation during orientation change. You can disable their spinning animation, which fixed this issue for us, by placing the following method in your main ViewController

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {//disables Apple's spinning animation when orientation changes which was causing app crashes due to memory issues

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)((0.01f) * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//failsafe
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    });

    [coordinator notifyWhenInteractionChangesUsingBlock:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    }];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

}
```